# Orphan Tracking in Sync Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server-2014, microsoft-sync-framework

I use Sync framework 2.1 to Synchronize SQL Server & Client. There seems to be changes in Client database when synchronization ends, but actually there is no changes done in Client database. SyncOperationStatistics always shows 20 uploads(in this scenario) .

> Start: 12/6/2015 8:34:36 PM 
>   Uploaded: 20
>   Downloaded: 0
>   End: 12/6/2015 8:34:37 PM

This keeps showing continuously,even though there are no changes.
Is there any way to resolve this,like cleanup orphan trackings ,without affecting the synchronization?
Thank you

Comment: have you checked if there are any conflicts during sync?

Comment: After debug, found some conflicts. hope can settle this. thanks

Comment: table with conflicts already settled. but the problem arose with another table. I did check for conflicts but there were none. But upload count keeps showing even though there are no uploads. please help me.